# How to use post method when clicking hyperlink in email body using Jmail?

Tags: asp.net, jmail

Im using Jmail to send an email from a classic asp page.

The email contains hyperlinks for service ratings that the customer can click, for a vote. 
Upon clicking this hyperlink an asp page opens in the browser with a thank you message. Currently the rating value and other info are passed as queryStrings as part of the hyperlink url to the asp page. How can i send this data as a post method instead of get from within the email?